How to fix Foliate 3 being unable to open any books after recent update?
After the recent update, the Foliate ebook reader cannot open ebooks anymore (in both APT and Snap versions).
This issue seems to occur in Ubuntu 22.04 with snap, as well as in Ubuntu 24.04.
$ foliate Alcott, Louisa May - Little Women.epub

(com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate:2289): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:51:13.769: Unknown key gtk-modules in /home/archisman/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
bwrap: setting up uid map: Permission denied

** (com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate:2289): ERROR **: 01:51:14.283: Failed to fully launch dbus-proxy: Child process exited with code 1
Trace/breakpoint trap

How to fix this issue?

To fix it permanently for all apps having such issues, check out https://askubuntu.com/q/1511854/124466

As a workaround, create the file /etc/apparmor.d/foliate (e.g. with sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/foliate) with the following contents.
# This profile allows everything and only exists to give the
# application a name instead of having the label "unconfined"

abi <abi/4.0>,
include <tunables/global>

profile foliate /usr/bin/foliate flags=(unconfined) {
  userns,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  include if exists <local/foliate>
}

Next, restart the apparmor.service.
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service

Now Foliate should function normally.
