How to make Balena Etcher and other appimages work in Ubuntu 24.04?
Balena Etcher is not opening in Ubuntu 24.04. How to run it?
I am using the appimage. Other appimages are not working either.

Related https://askubuntu.com/q/1510040/124466

Due to recent changes in apparmor, none of the electron apps (except VS Code) work out of the box in Ubuntu 24.04.
Temporary solution: The workaround is to run the following command.
sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0

It has to be run again after rebooting.
To make it permanent, run the command
echo 'kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns = 0' | 
  sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/20-apparmor-donotrestrict.conf

Note: Disabling the apparmor restrictions in 24.04 does not make it more vulnerable than 22.04. Please read this for more details, and use it at your own risk.

Thanks for helping out! According to https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-notes/39890#security-improvements-14, I believe using an AppArmor profile would be a better solution but I don’t know how to create one for Etcher’s AppImage release. Would you happen to know how?

Unfortunately there is no way to create an apparmor profile for etcher as far as I know.
