Enabling Zoom, Etc. on Apple Magic Trackpad 2 (Bluetooth)
I've just picked up an Apple Magic Trackpad 2, for use with Figma. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4, and the device works as a basic trackpad; movement, tap-to-click, btn-2 and btn-3 click emulation, etc. What I haven't gotten working is the pinch-to-zoom, rotate, etc.
I've been digging on this for a few hours and read a number of questions both here and on Super User SE. All of the questions and answers are several years old, and all refer to the AMT2 as a USB device. Mine is set up as a Bluetooth device, however. I tried connecting it as a USB device (it connects and charges via a Lighting-to-USB-C cable), and now the device shows up in xinput --list twice (even though I've completely removed it as a BT device). Further, I have noticed from xinput list-props that it is using the libinput driver instead of the Synaptics driver. This is important because the solutions that involve using xinput to adjust settings don't match this device when they run. I did try changing "Synaptics" to "libinput" in the commands, but no difference in result.
For reference, I'm doing this in Xorg. I haven't tried Wayland in a while, but last time I did try it didn't get along well with my NVIDIA graphics card. That may have improved since then, as NV is using more-open drivers these days.
The output from xinput --list is:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Signature M650 L                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logi K650                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]

I don't know if that will help.

Pinch to zoom works out of the box with Wayland in Firefox and Chrome in Ubuntu 24.04 (also, in 24.04, the compatibility with Nvidia+Wayland improved). I recommend you upgrade.
X.Org does not support pinch-to-zoom very well. You can still get basic pinch-to-zoom in XOrg with touchegg (https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) and this extension(https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg), but it zooms the the whole screen rather than just the browser.

Argh, I was afraid that this might mean switching to Wayland before I'm really ready. I haven't jumped to 24.04 mostly due to a lack of spare cycles, but also because I usually wait for a .1 update-release. How steady/stable is it so far?

In 24.04 I did not have any problem except this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511654/how-to-make-balena-etcher-work-in-ubuntu-24-04. Please try it in a live session, and if the apps you generally use work there, then back up data in the home folder and fresh install (instead of upgrading).

I was already planning to fresh install. The SSD in this box is about 8 years old, figure I'll put a new one in and install fresh.

I don't know if old SSDs become slower. Unless you are having problems, just reinstall on the same SSD after backing up the data in the home folder
