How to permanently disable Ubuntu's new AppArmor user namespace creation restrictions in order to run appimages and web-based apps?
I want to run the command sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0 at startup to make etcher work.
How to run such a command with sudo during startup, without entering the password?

Isn't that something that should be done via a drop-in sysctl.d file, rather than a sudo command?

@steeldriver I don't know how to use it. Would you like to write an answer?

Commands run at system startup are run as root (UID 0), so using sudo is unnecessary.

Related: Will disabling AppArmor restrictions on 24.04 make a difference from 22.04

Summary: Run the following command and reboot.
echo 'kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns = 0' | 
  sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/20-apparmor-donotrestrict.conf


The sudo command is really intended for elevating privileges in an interactive session - in particular, it expects to read the authenticating user's password via a tty (or other interactive mechanism specified via SUDO_ASKPASS). Any time you want to run a command with elevated privileges non-interactively, there's usually a better way to do so - for example

via a root crontab entry
via a systemd system service

In the case of sysctl, there's an even better option: via a drop-in configuration file. From man sysctl.d:

DESCRIPTION
   At boot, systemd-sysctl.service(8) reads configuration files from the
   above directories to configure sysctl(8) kernel parameters.


So you can simply create a file in /etc/sysctl.d and add the name = value there - either with your favorite text editor, or for example using
echo 'kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns = 0' | 
  sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/20-apparmor-donotrestrict.conf

(aside from the .conf suffix, the filename is arbitrary - I suggest you choose something that is meaningful to you).
Reboot.

My current kernel (5.15.0-105-generic) doesn't appear to have the kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns parameter, so I tested with kernel.unprivileged_userns_apparmor_policy instead.

About potential security concerns: It may seem that this may opens up a lot of security issues, but that is really not the case because a malware which gains administrative privileges can revert such restriction and do anything. And a malware with administrative privileges can basically do anything. The only way you can increase security is to stick to the official repositories and not install untrusted apps at all, and not give your password to them. Other distributions like Mint and Solus are reverting this change in apparmor. Other distributions like Debian, Fedora, or Arch don't have this restriction at all. Also, Ubuntu 22.04 and prior versions did not have this apparmor policy, and your system would be no more insecure than Ubuntu 22.04. However, you are at your own risk if you decide to follow this method (the point of this note is, you are always at your own risk when you use GNU/Linux. You have to cautiously decide what to install).

Thanks for helping out! According to https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-notes/39890#security-improvements-14, I believe using an AppArmor profile would be a better solution but I don’t know how to create one for Etcher’s AppImage release. Would you happen to know how?

@sunknudsen no sorry - apparmor is a closed book to me :(

Nowadays apparmor provides an apparmor profile for etcher and disabling apparmor restrictions is not needed anymore, it should even be avoided because it introduces security issues. If the etcher appimage is used, follow the example in this answer to create your own apparmor profile.

Thanks for pointing out!
