Memgraph Lab won't start on Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop
I recently installed Memgraph and Memgraph Lab from the official downloads page and encountered Memgraph failing to start- this was due to Neo4j using the same port (though the error logs were completely, entirely, absolutely useless).
Memgraph Lab did start exactly once, but it refused to start after I removed it with apt and reinstalled it with dpkg.
Once again I am finding the error logs unhelpful. Things I've tried:

Disabling apparmor (though Memgraph Lab doesn't appear to be under apparmor's jurisdiction).

Installing Memgraph Lab via the "Direct Download Links" - using the .deb package for Ubuntu 24.04 AMD64 of course.

Checking the systemctl logs

Invoking memgraph-lab from Terminal. This gives the following output:
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/opt/Memgraph
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

/opt/Memgraph indeed does not exist, so I suspect this is the issue; however, the .deb installers don't seem to be creating it. Presumably it was created the first time when Memgraph Lab successfully launched? But then why was it deleted and why can't it be recreated?

Other Electron apps like Visual Studio Code (non-snap, non-flatpak) are working fine.

I am able to launch Memgraph Lab via Terminal with memgraph-lab --no-sandbox but this is a band aid.



Since it works with no-sandbox, it must be a result of Ubuntu's apparmor bug which prevents most electron apps from running. The permanent fix is described here https://askubuntu.com/q/1511854/124466
